# MongoClient vs MongoServer .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

В [официальной документации](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/N_MongoDB_Driver.htm) документации об **MongoClient** пишут:

> Base class for implementors of IMongoClient.

А об **MongoServer**:

> Represents a MongoDB server (either a single instance or a replica set) and the settings used to access it. This class is thread-safe.

С одной стороны - оба класса дают возможность получить **IMongoDatabase** и продолжить дальше работу с базой. Но с другой стороны - зачем нужны тогда эти **два** класса?

В каких случаях использовать **MongoServer**, а в каких **MongoClient** - непонятно. Собственно, в этом и прошу помочь мне разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoServer` - это класс из сборки `MongoDB.Driver.Legacy` - старой версии драйвера. Используйте `MongoClient`.